# Reference on Riesz representation theorem for $L^p(0,T,X)$ spaces.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, riesz-representation-theorem

[Brezis Functional Analysis book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Haim%20brezis%20functional%20analysis&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=mdbrU862FqjmsASV24GQDw&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Haim%20brezis%20functional%20analysis&f=false) proves the following Riesz representation theorems for [usual $L^p(\Omega)$ spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces):

[image]

[image]

In what book can we find an analogous of these theorems for $L^p(0,T,X)$ spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%0 Book
%A Diestel, J.
%A Uhl, J. J., Jr.
%T Vector measures
%Z With a foreword by B. J. Pettis;
   Mathematical Surveys, No. 15
%I American Mathematical Society
%C Providence, R.I.
%D 1977
%P xiii+322
%L MR0453964 (56 \#12216)
```

Chapter IV